# how to create a angular table row to have a collapsed row

Tags: json, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a table which will have collapsed rows that have 2nd level info, but not all the rows will have this 2nd level data.

How can i write a controller to only show a 2nd level collapse row if the JSON script has a 2nd level?

Comment: Could you post a sample of your json?

Comment: {
 "id": "0001",
 "type": "donut",
 "name": "Cake",
 "ppu": 0.55,
 "batters": "whatever",
 "topping":
  [
   { "id": "5001", "type": "None" },
   { "id": "5002", "type": "Glazed" },
   { "id": "5005", "type": "Sugar" },
   { "id": "5007", "type": "Powdered Sugar" },
   { "id": "5006", "type": "Chocolate with Sprinkles" },
   { "id": "5003", "type": "Chocolate" },
   { "id": "5004", "type": "Maple" }
  ]
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the following json defined in your controller:

```
$scope.cakes = [{ "id": "0001", "type": "donut", "name": "Cake", 
                "ppu": 0.55, "batters": "whatever", 
                "topping": [ { "id": "5001", "type": "None" }, 
                             { "id": "5002", "type": "Glazed" }, 
                             { "id": "5005", "type": "Sugar" }, 
                             { "id": "5007", "type": "Powdered Sugar" }, 
                             { "id": "5006", "type": "Chocolate with Sprinkles" }, 
                             { "id": "5003", "type": "Chocolate" }, 
                             { "id": "5004", "type": "Maple" } ] }, 
                { "id": "0002", "type": "cupcake", "name": "Cupcake", 
                                    "ppu": 0.60, "batters": "whatever", 
                                    "topping": [] },
                { "id": "0003", "type": "muffin", "name": "Muffin", 
                                    "ppu": 0.25, "batters": "whatever", 
                                    "topping": [] }
                ];
```

you can selectively show a second row in a table where cake.topping.length is greater than 0:

```
<table>
    <tr ng-repeat-start="cake in cakes">
        <td>{{cake.type}}</td><td>{{cake.name}}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat-end ng-show="cake.topping.length>0">
        <td ng-repeat="t in cake.topping">{{t.type}}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```